# How Can I get my DL to style properly?

Tags: css, list

I'm just wonderfin if anyone can tell me if I am on the right track to styling this properly?
with my CSS and HTML like this

```
#bulletsBox{
    position: relative;
    height: 382px;
    width: 736px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 48px;
    padding-right: 102px;
    padding-left: 102px;
}
dl#Bullets,#Bullets2, #Bullets3, #Bullets4, #Bullets5, #Bullets6{
    position: relative;
    height: 210px;
    width: 210px;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#Bullets dt,#Bullets2 dt,#Bullets3 dt, #Bullets4 dt,#Bullets5 dt,#Bullets6 dt{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #969b94;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    }
#Bullets dd,#Bullets2 dd ,#Bullets3 dd, #Bullets4 dd,#Bullets5 dd,#Bullets6 dd{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #686869;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 18px;
    }



<div id="bulletsBox">
                <dl id="Bullets">
                    <dt>web standards</dt>
                    <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum malesuada velit, sed fringilla nulla posuere at. Donec dapibus cursus rutrum. Praesent ultrices facilisis vehicula. Praesent vitae urna non magna dictum porttitor. Mauris ut ligula enim.</dd>
                </dl>

                <dl id="Bullets2">
                <dt>web standards</dt>
                    <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum malesuada velit, sed fringilla nulla posuere at. Donec dapibus cursus rutrum. Praesent ultrices facilisis vehicula. Praesent vitae urna non magna dictum porttitor. Mauris ut ligula enim.</dd>
              </dl>

              <dl id="Bullets3" style="margin:0px">
                <dt>web standards</dt>
                    <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum malesuada velit, sed fringilla nulla posuere at. Donec dapibus cursus rutrum. Praesent ultrices facilisis vehicula. Praesent vitae urna non magna dictum porttitor. Mauris ut ligula enim.</dd>
              </dl>

              <dl id="Bullets4">
                  <dt>web standards</dt>
                    <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum malesuada velit, sed fringilla nulla posuere at. Donec dapibus cursus rutrum. Praesent ultrices facilisis vehicula. Praesent vitae urna non magna dictum porttitor. Mauris ut ligula enim.</dd>
              </dl>

              <dl id="Bullets5">
                <dt>web standards</dt>
                    <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum malesuada velit, sed fringilla nulla posuere at. Donec dapibus cursus rutrum. Praesent ultrices facilisis vehicula. Praesent vitae urna non magna dictum porttitor. Mauris ut ligula enim.</dd>
              </dl>

              <dl id="Bullets6" style="margin:0px">
                <dt>web standards</dt>
                    <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum malesuada velit, sed fringilla nulla posuere at. Donec dapibus cursus rutrum. Praesent ultrices facilisis vehicula. Praesent vitae urna non magna dictum porttitor. Mauris ut ligula enim.</dd>
              </dl>

                </div><!--end of bulletsBox-->
```

it displays how I want it to in Dreamweaver like [this](http://doublezerofilms.com/Screenshot.png)

but when I veiw it in a browser it looks like [this](http://www.doublezerofilms.com/doublezero-template.html)

Comment: The link to your screenshot produces a 404 error.

Comment: One suggestion at first glance, if you're applying the same styles to all dl, dt, and dd elements you don't have to explicitly name each one. Just call `#bulletsBox dl`, `#bulletsBox dt`, or `#bulletsBox dd` to make it easier. If you have say 20 more bullet points in the future it would be a nightmare to update your css.

Comment: I had it that way originally. I was concerned that there might be a problem having multiple list id's with the same name. Is that ok to do?

Comment: Dreamweaver is a poor tool for previewing. It's handy for manually sizing tables, but that's about it. Always use a real browser.

Comment: If you need multiple IDs use class names instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the `display:inline` on `#Bullets dt,#Bullets2 dt,#Bullets3 dt, #Bullets4 dt,#Bullets5 dt,#Bullets6 dt` and just put `float:left` instead.

You'll also want to correct the inline style of `margin:0px` on `#Bullets3` and `#Bullets6` and replace it with `margin-right:0px` since I think that's really the only `margin` value you want to override.

Finally, just use `#bulletsBox dl` to refer to all the `#Bullets` elements inside of it. Easier to read and write :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `float:left;` to your rule `dl#Bullets, #Bullets2, #Bullets3, #Bullets4, #Bullets5, #Bullets6 {...`

Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wMCfp/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You're working too hard. Let CSS inheritance do the work. All these extra class names are not required.

Note: you do not need to use `position:relative` unless you plan to use absolute positioning on a child element.

```
<div id="bulletsBox">
    <dl>
        <dt>web standards</dt>
        <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum malesuada velit, sed fringilla nulla posuere at. Donec dapibus cursus rutrum. Praesent ultrices facilisis vehicula. Praesent vitae urna non magna dictum porttitor. Mauris ut ligula enim.</dd>
    </dl>

    <dl>
    <dt>web standards</dt>
        <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum malesuada velit, sed fringilla nulla posuere at. Donec dapibus cursus rutrum. Praesent ultrices facilisis vehicula. Praesent vitae urna non magna dictum porttitor. Mauris ut ligula enim.</dd>
    </dl>

    <dl>
    <dt>web standards</dt>
        <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum malesuada velit, sed fringilla nulla posuere at. Donec dapibus cursus rutrum. Praesent ultrices facilisis vehicula. Praesent vitae urna non magna dictum porttitor. Mauris ut ligula enim.</dd>
    </dl>

    <dl>
      <dt>web standards</dt>
        <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum malesuada velit, sed fringilla nulla posuere at. Donec dapibus cursus rutrum. Praesent ultrices facilisis vehicula. Praesent vitae urna non magna dictum porttitor. Mauris ut ligula enim.</dd>
    </dl>

    <dl>
    <dt>web standards</dt>
        <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum malesuada velit, sed fringilla nulla posuere at. Donec dapibus cursus rutrum. Praesent ultrices facilisis vehicula. Praesent vitae urna non magna dictum porttitor. Mauris ut ligula enim.</dd>
    </dl>

    <dl>
    <dt>web standards</dt>
        <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum malesuada velit, sed fringilla nulla posuere at. Donec dapibus cursus rutrum. Praesent ultrices facilisis vehicula. Praesent vitae urna non magna dictum porttitor. Mauris ut ligula enim.</dd>
    </dl>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bulletsBox {
    height: 382px;
    width: 736px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 48px;
    padding-right: 102px;
    padding-left: 102px;
}
#bulletsBox dl {
    height: 210px;
    width: 210px;
    float:left;   <--- added this
    margin-right: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#bulletsBox dt {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #969b94;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    }
#bulletsBox dd {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #686869;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 18px;
    }
```